# Populate listview from parse one at a time

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I am new to android and I am using parse cloud. I am using a tutorial to populate my listview here is the link of tutorial [Android Parse.com ListView Images and Texts Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/). The code is working fine but the problem is I have to wait until all parse objects are added to List but I want to show one by one as the objects are fetched. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the items one by one to your adapter in a `OnProgressUpdate(YourObject object)` Method. Every time you fetch an item you call `publishProgress(TheItemObject)`.

Bur remember to initialize your Adapter and ListView in the OnCreate method then, you will get NullPointers otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned tutorial is one way of doing it,But according to parse there is a small difference of doing it. First i would recommend reading out
[Parse.com Android guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-retrieving-objects-from-the-local-datastore) and go to ParseQueryAdapter section.

here's a general idea what you should do.

1) Create a ParseQueryAdapter (Ex : Wish list Adapter). This is just like in Android adapter. In here you

```
public class WishListPQAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Post> { 
}
```

2) You need to query parse data through a query factory (ex : Wishlist)

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post>() {
            public ParseQuery<Post> create() {
                ParseQuery<Post> query = Post.getQuery();
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                return query;
            }
        };
```

3) pass in the factory created above to this adaper.

```
WishItemPQAdapter wishItemAdapter = new WishItemPQAdapter(this, factory);
```

4) Initiate list view and set adapter to it. (Best is to initiate listview in onCreate. )

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_wish_item_suggestions);
listView.setAdapter(wishItemAdapter);
```

This is the Parse.com recommended way of developing and with this you will have multiple advantages like

1. Customizing the Query
2. Customizing the Rows
3. Loading Remote Images in Rows
4. More Lifecycle Methods
5. Pagination
6. Auto-loading of Data

Hope this helps